# jquery mobile 1.3 beta webmatrix 2 : href link in popup to another cshtml page not working

Tags: popup

Request your urgent help, as always :-)

This is an issue with a .cshtml Page of WebMatrix2 using jQueryMobile V 1.3.0 Beta 1.

In my cshtml page I have the following footer with an navbar; which has a 'Select' button that would show a Popup with id = 'PopupMenu' when Clicked, (Code as shown below).

The Popup contains a Listview with ita listitems having links to other cshtml pages, (also Code as shown below).

When I Click the Select Button in the Footer, It works fine and shows the Popup with the Listview properly.

But when I click the listitem, it does not take me to the required page, i.e. Page1 or Page2

```
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
     <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade">Select</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-overlay-theme="b">
       <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="width:180px;" data-theme="b">
         <li><a data-rel="popup" href="page1.cshtml">Select Page 1</a></li>
         <li><a data-rel="popup" href="page2.cshtml">Select Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

So my questions are:

1. Are the links in a Popup supposed to link only to the contents of the same Page?
2. If the answer to the above question is YES, then is there a work-around to achieve what I want to do?

Thanks.

Ratna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to code error.

Answers to my own Questions:

1. NO!
2. Does not arise!
   The ListItems of the Listview in the Popup with id='popupMenu' contain Quote data-rel="popup" UnQuote. This is incorrect and should be removed.

Now it works fine.

Thanks, Ratna